# How can I hide a label when tap has finished?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts, user-interaction

When I tap on the chart it shows a value and highlight indicator.  How can I remove them after the tap finishes?

```
    func SetChart(_ dataPoints: [Date], values: [Double], lineChartView: LineChartView, description: String)  {

 lineChartDataSet.highlightEnabled = true
 lineChartView.highlightPerDragEnabled = true
 lineChartDataSet.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
}



 func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
     print("\(entry.y))
 }
```

Comment: Well how are you showing it when the touch event happens?? Target-Action ?? Gesture Recognizers??

Comment: I use iOS Charts library and when I do highlightedEnabled = true they just appear

Answer (score 0):

Tap does not work that way - [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068724/ios-tap-gesture-state-begin-doesnt-hit). What highlights your values is probably a pan gesture. It does not seem that the Charts framework supports the behaviour you described. You will have to implement your own [touch down gesture recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628133/uitapgesturerecognizer-make-it-work-on-touch-down-not-touch-up). It is worth to check BarLineChartViewBase class, as you might need to subclass it and use it in your own subclass of LineChart. To unhighlight value use `lineChart.highlightValue(nil)`. I hope that someone knows about the better way, but I worry that it does not exist.